# Music on Tannis Esther

Tags: purim, music, fast-days

Can you listen to music on Tannis Esther? (are haircuts allowed? it was asked but I want to know if Tannis esther is different as it seems to be Less of a fast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may litsen to music on Taanis Esther

> On Taanis Esther one is permitted to
>   bathe, listen to music, and to wear
>   new clothing. Taanis Esther is
>   different than the other fast days
>   because it is unrelated to the
>   destruction of the Bais Hamikdash. S’U
>   Siach Yitzchok 360, Piskei Tshuvos
>   686:2:6

http://matzav.com/hilchos-purim-carrying-the-megillah-on-shabbos

You may take a haircut on Taanis Esther

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=4&ClipID=1969

Comment: Shkoach for the SHUT for my Huntch